# Using Calibri with DOMpdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using DOMpdf to generate some letters with PHP. My client has requested that I use Calibri as the body font, which I have attempted to convert to a DOMpdf-readable format using this tool: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/load_font.php.

Unfortunately when it comes to generating the file I am getting PHP errors complaining about an undefined index:

```
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index:  
Filename: lib/class.pdf.php
Line Number: 3230
```

I have looked into the error and it seems like it's something to do with the bounding box definition of the file. I'm not sure what's going on here.

I am using the following line in my document:

```
font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
```

The key in dompdf_font_family_cache is 'calibri' and refers to files that exist.

Has anyone had any experience at all with the DOMPDF library and the Calibri font? Any help here would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: did you know that calibri is not a free font? It belong to Microsoft and normally you'd "have" to [pay a license](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=287) to use it in your application.. it doesn't solve your problem, but this is just a comment =)

Comment: I thought it might be! Might have something to do with the problems with conversion, thanks for the heads up an invoice is heading to the client now :)

Answer (score 1):

you may have used the EXE parser, you should use the PHP one, which works better.
DOMPDF won't need this anymore in the next version, as you'll be able to specify new fonts using the [@font-face CSS feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face). This is already available in the version from the SVN trunk.

**EDIT**: It is a problem with the version of DOMPDF you are using (0.5.2). The dompdf_font_family_cache file doesn't have the right format (which has changed a little bit in 0.6 beta). You need to remove the `<?php` at the beginning of this file and possibly the `?>` at the end.

Comment: Fabien, thanks for your reply. I used the PHP parser, the EXE refused to play!